# Why apache only asks once to authenticate?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

I am trying to set some authentication to one of my folders in apache server.

This is the look of my apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FllowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

in my /var/www directory I have a directory called demo
so insade demo I have this .htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
Require user demo
```

And have allready created the demo password in that file.

My problem is that once you have authenticated in one client if you reload or go to another file of that directory there is no authentication asked.

What I want is that everytime you reload the server ask you for the authentication.

Comment: The user's browser remembers the credentials for a certain time or until it is closed. It's like a session.

Comment: @ÜberLem even if i say not to safe the password?

Comment: The option to save the password is to save it "forever", meaning that even if the browser is closed and reopened, it won't ask for credentials since it was told to save the password. Please have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: @ÜberLem undertood, thank you.